# What are some objective negatives to namespaces in Typescript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, namespaces, bundling-and-minification

I've seen a lot in different articles in the internet and heard a lot that the namespaces are old and evil things. I've heard a lot that you should use modules with a module loader instead of namespaces, but I just don't understand what are the objective benefits of using them. I've read about different arguments against namespaces, but they just seem not so convincing to me. I'll list some of the arguments and you guys please try to explain me with some real world examples why those are valid:

- Namespaces create at least 1 global variable. But what's the problem with that? I don't care if there is a global variable called angular. What harm is it going to do?
- With modules, the consumer decides what to name imported variable. what the ability of naming imports really gives me? How likely is it that there will be 2 variables named angular? And in those rare cases when there will be duplicate variable names can't we just do this (I haven't tested this, but it should work in theory):

  ```
  var someOtherName = angular;

  var angular = function() {
  };
  ```
- Modules with module loaders make bundling easier because they put scripts in right order. But why wouldn't they do that when you explicitly tell them the order, by adding your imports on top of each file? Similarly, Typescript builds your JavaScript in right order when you put the triple slash references on top of your files with "outFile" option in tsconfig.json. How is that different from imports?
- Module loaders improve the performance. This one is really confusing me. Let's say I generate one giant JavaScript file using either Typescript or .NET framework's bundling tools, wouldn't the performance be the same because we will have 1 file in either case? SystemJS does dynamic loading of those scripts as needed. This one makes more sense, but still if I end up having a 25kb JavaScript file, how much performance gain would I really have if it loads each kb on demand? After all, it's just 25kb.
- Even assuming that modules and module loaders are better than bundling into one file and referencing it in html, if I use module loader for building a library, does that mean the anyone that uses my library needs to install the loader dependency too?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) Close reason: *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."* and/or too broad (ask **one** question/question).

Comment: I don't think the OP was looking for opinions, but rather some educated examples of why namespaces should or should not be used with the Angular framework and how well they behave with tree shaking. I've found that this information is hard to find. There should, however, be hard facts about the nature of namespaces in regards to tree shaking and eagerly/lazy loading. This question should not have been closed.

Answer (score 9):

There are many reasons that using namespace consider as a bad idea nowadays in JavaScript.
All these reasons apply to TypeScript as it is just a superset of JavaScript.

You have self-answered some of them but may not see their significance.
I'll try to address them as much as I can.

## Implicit dependency order

When your code uses some libraries through namespace,
you implicitly create a dependency between your code and the library you are using.

This means you have to either manage the dependency yourself so that they are loaded correctly,
or you need to instruct the compiler/bundler so they can arrange the loading order correctly.

This means you have an out-of-band place to manage this information and it is error prone.
What if tomorrow you stop using this library? Will you remember to exclude it?
It is much better to let your tool to do their job.

## Namespace conflict

This is a common reason people object using global namespacing.
You may think that this rarely happens but one example is `lodash` vs `underscore`.

## Namespace versioning

This is another form of namespace conflict.
If your code and one of your libraries use the same library `x` but different version (and `x` expose in global namespace `x`), which version should it be in the global namespace `x`?

Module solves this problem.

(disclaimer: currently TypeScript typings system does not handle multiple versions correctly, so you may see some issue and need to work around it).

## Prohibit tree shaking

With ESM, bundler such as `rollup` and `webpack` can perform tree-shaking.
Using a library through namespace gives no information to the bundler to analyze your code and tree-shake away the bits that you don't need.

## Rigidity

When you expose your library through namespace, the internal structure of your library is exposed and that means you can't refactor your code without creating breaking changes to your consumer.

Yes, you can somehow avoid that by carefully creating adapters or alias, but that will make your code much harder to maintain and most likely end up in a mess.

## Security

This is debatable but making your code accessible in global namespace means your code and potential some states can be easily accessible and modifiable by other code.

There are many more reasons I'm sure but these are what I can think of right now.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but you listed those things that may cause problems in theory. For example, I don't think that I'd use both lodash and underscore together, or have the same library in different versions. Even then, those type of problems are such that can exist in many other languages such as C#, but we have been dealing with those with other means and not discouraging namespaces in C#.

Comment: These issue doesn't only apply to your application, but also to libraries. Before module loader, JavaScript does not have the concept of Linker and DLL, which solves some of the problems in other languages such as C#. It is not the case in JavaScript. It is a scripting language. Using namespace basically for going that flexibility and make it very limiting.

Comment: If you'd use 2 objects with the same namespace and class name, you'd need to alias them in C#, but that is such a rare case that I have never done that. Do you think there may be a problem "aliasing" those objects like I did in my point 2 in the question?

Comment: Seems like you are still confused between a script language and a language like C#. If global namespace is the mechanism to deliver the library, there is no way for you to create the alias. One just overwrites the other, based on load order. There is no compilation step in between to solve that problem.